# How to get the number of digits of an integer?

Tags: c, string, file, integer, structure

The program below is sufficent enouhgh to find the length of any string length that is given to the input, however, i need to find the length of an integer variable, rather than a string.

Entering a number to this does work, but not if i scan s as a int type.

```
int main()
{
   char s[1000];
   char i;
   int u=5;
   do
   {
       char s[1000];
       char i;
       int u=5;
       system("cls");
       printf("Enter a string: ");
       scanf("%s",s);
       for(i=0; s[i]!='\0'; ++i);

       printf("Length of string: %d",i);
       getch();
  }
 while(u==5);
getch();
}
```

So all i need is either this little program modified to accept intger variables, or a way to  transform a calculated int variable into a string.

Any ideas?

Edit: Length = Amount of characters so 25 has 2, 3456 has 4 etc

Comment: No need to apologize. Just fix them. The indents, I mean.

Comment: Please define "length of an integer variable". Thanks.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with databases, edited your title to reflect what you're really after.

Comment: It's been changed,for me at least it says How to get the number of digits of an integer?

Comment: Do you want to read an integer as an integer i,e with `%d` and count number of digits in that integer?

Comment: If you have a C99 compiler, `ndigits = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", value);` works.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the length of n in base m with the formula:

```
ceil(log(n + 1, m))
```

Where ceil is the ceiling (round up) function, and `log(a, b)` is logarithms of a in base b.

Comment: There aren't any powers being used?

Comment: @user3503792, `m` is the base so in your case it's 10. This function is IMO the most elegant solution rather then using sprintf variants.

Comment: Also, if the value is zero, this fails

Comment: @SGeorgiades: that can be easily rectified with abs() and then the only problem is zero. So the entire implementation can be: n == 0 ? 1 : ceil(log(abs(n), m))

Comment: @LieRyan: except that you haven't counted the "minus sign" in your length.  Maybe (n == 0) ? 1 : ceil(log(abs(n),m) + (n < 0) ? 1 : 0;

Comment: @SGeorgiades: You don't actually need the conditionals, this will handle zero and negatives: `ceil(log(abs(n) + 1, m)) + (n <= 0)`. PS: there is a *very* serious bug in my original formula, it's been fixed now, I'm surprised nobody had noticed it for so long.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the below code to find the number of digits of an integer:

```
int count=0;
while(n!=0)
{
  n/=10;             
  ++count;
}
```

Where `n` is your input integer and `count` will be the it's length.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read an integer as an integer i,e with `%d` and count number of digits in that integer, have a look at below code snippet.

```
int no,length=0;
printf("Enter number");
scanf("%d",&no);
while(no!=0)
{
length+=1;
no=no%10;
}
printf("Length=%d",length);
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine the number of characters to print a decimal number (assuming `value` is the `int`), you could do the following:

```
int intlen = 0;
if (value < 0)         // for negative values, allow a char for the minus sign
{
    value = -value;
    ++intlen;
}
while (value >= 10)     // as long as the value is 1 or more,
{
    value /= 10;        // divide by 10,
    ++intlen;           // ...and add one to the length
}
++intlen;               // add one for last digit (even if it's zero)
```

It's probably easier to use the ceil/log function described above, but this one does not require the math library (if that is an issue)

Another brute-force approach would be as follows:

```
char temp[12];
int intlen = sprintf(temp,"%i",value);
```

This utilizes the fact that `sprintf` returns the number of characters placed in the string buffer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
                 int count=1,n;
                 scanf("%d",&n);
                 while(n/=10)
                       count++;
                 printf("result=%d",count);
}
```

count gives the number of digits in number n